# Angular material validation on submit

Tags: angular, forms, validation, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material input fields and there is a problem that fields become red as soon as user does something to it.

However, I need these fields to stay "valid" until the form is submitted, so that the user starts seeing errors **only after** clicking submit button.

In casual inputs I've used that thing `<input [class.ng-invalid]="control.invalid && submitted">` thus it starts turning red after clicking "Submit".

However that didn't help me when I tried to apply this to `matInput`

```
<mat-form-field class="w-100">
    <input [id]="id" matInput
           [class.ng-invalid]="control.errors && submitted"
           [placeholder]="getPlaceholder()"
           [formControl]="control">
</mat-form-field>
```

How do I achieve displaying errors only after submitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by creating own ErrorStateMatch as described in https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown